# Embed a m file to Simulink

Tags: arduino, real-time, simulink, video-tracking

I am working on ball and plate in Matlab Simulink. I have a ball tracking Matlab file. How can I run it in Simulink? I want position data from ball tracking Matlab file. I tried s function from user defined functions but my code is not working because of videoinput error. What should I do?

Comment: Show your efforts. What have you done so far? Where exactly are you getting the error? Maybe post some code so that people here can help you.

Comment: i added the tracking code so sory for first entry

Answer (score 0):

Code intended for simulink (embedded) coder must be of such nature that code can be generated from it. This means that only a subset of Matlab functions are supported.
Typically code that is to be supported for code generation should have the "pragma"

**%#codegen**

inside the function definition.

What to do depends on your goal:

A) If you want to generate code from your model:

You need to rewrite the function in code that is not tagged as invalid for %#codegen. (Some work included - sorry...)

B) If you just want to run in simulink:

Use the **coder.extrinsic** mechanism. This is just a directive that you put inside the matlab function (block) code and tell simulink that you want to use a matlab function that is outside of the codegen specification. After you have done that you can call your normal function (put it in a function m-file). However, if you try to generate code; that specific function call will be ignored. The rest of the code will try to execute on best effort.

Final note; if you are developing (command prompt) functions that you might someday want to call or include in matlab function blocks in simulink, you should throw in the %#codegen pragma so that it helps you avoid functions that cannot be used in code generation.